# access jquery unserialized data using getData in cakephp 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I'm using cakephp 3.4

I have a form to submit values using ajax.

```
<?= $this->Form->create(null, ['id' => 'search-form']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('keyword') ?>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Search'), ['id' => 'search-submit']); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

and sending this data to action using

```
$('#search-submit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('/dashboard/custom-search/ajax-search',
    {
        data: $('#search-form').serialize()
    }, function (response)
    {
        $('#search-result').html(response);
    });
    return false;
});
```

In `ajaxSearch` action when I debug request data

```
debug($this->request->getData());
```

It gives

```
[
    'data' => '_method=POST&keyword=world'
]
```

But when I try

```
debug($this->request->getData('keyword'));
```

It gives

```
null
```

**How can I get serialized data in an action?** or **How to unserialize data in action/controller?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to change is the way you are posting your serialized data to:

```
$.post('/dashboard/custom-search/ajax-search',
    $('#search-form').serialize(),
    function (response){
        $('#search-result').html(response);
});
```

This way your `getData()` will return data in expected format.

Full info about passing serialized data via `jQuery.post()` can be found here: [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)